# Line break (\n) not working in ios when escaped via StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava

Tags: android, ios, string, stringescapeutils

I am using `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'` library to convert emoji from my android app so that it can easily decoded in ios. So in my android app to encode string into `unicode` i am using this method `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` its working fine emoji sent via android app showing in ios but when i sent data which contains some line break, in ios it shows `\n` instead of showing text in new line.I tried

```
        val actualText=editText.text.toString()
        val oldText=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(actualText).toString()
        val newText=oldText.replace("\n", "\r\n")
```

but its not working.

Comment: Why `\r\n`? Apple has long been using `\n` as newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot i found the issue. 
for these statements:

```
        val actualText=editText.text.toString()
        val oldText=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(actualText).toString()
        val newText=oldText.replace("\n", "\r\n")
```

This picture(output) will clear everything

[image]

after using StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava for old text \n not considered as escape sequence character. So i changed replacement statement to:

```
val reviewText=oldText.replace(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("\n"), "\r\n")
```

and then output is:

[image]

after this in ios app instead of showing \n it shows text to the new line.